# Cannot retrieve correct max date from Hive table?

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql

I am abit confused. When I use `max(send_date)` I get `2018-02-04 23:59:51.0`. However, when I use `max(TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(send_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))))` or `TO_DATE(from_unixtime(max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(send_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))))`, I get `2018-01-31`!!

Why?

```
select max(send_date) from mytable;
```

Aso, when I use `WHERE TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(send_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')))  = '2018-02-04'`, I get the restult `0`, but it's not true.

Comment: What is the data type of `send_date`?  I am guessing a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: It's `string` as far as I can see using `describe mytable`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Maybe I should adjust `yyyy-mm-dd` to the actual input format which includes hours, minutes, seconds?

Comment: Do you need to compare only by `yyyy-mm-dd` or do you need to include hours, minutes, seconds etc?

Comment: @Bala: I found my issue, I had to use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead of `yyyy-mm-dd`:)))

Answer (score 0):

I was using incorrect conversion format. In particular, I used `yyyy-mm-dd` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd`

More details can be found here:
http://bigdataprogrammers.com/string-date-conversion-hive/

Answer (score 0):

When using `to_date` with Hive you don't even have to specify that format because by default it returns that format.  Here is an example

```
  select max(to_date(d1)), max(d1), min(to_date(d1)), min(d1) from (
    select '2018-02-04 23:59:51.0' as d1
    union all
    select '2018-02-04 23:59:59.0' as d1
    union all
    select '2018-01-31 23:59:51.0' as d1
    union all
    select '2018-01-31 23:59:59.0' as d1
  ) tbl
```

Output

```
OK
2018-02-04  2018-02-04 23:59:59.0   2018-01-31  2018-01-31 23:59:51.0
Time taken: 27.547 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```